# Pay a very high price

Tags: idiom-requests

What are English idioms for "you have to pay a very high price to get the thing that you want"?

Comment: Sorry, user626528, that *is* an idiom. Did you mean something like "synonymous phrases" or roughly what, please?

Remembering that "you have to pay a very high price to get the thing that you want" is *not* an English idiom, but a lengthy phrase which happens to include such an idiom, perhaps as a translations from another language… where specifically did your original phrase come from, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin does it really matter where it comes from? I just need some idioms that have this meaning.

Comment: Then why did you ask here, rather than using a search engine, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin if I can't ask questions here, what is this site for?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I know no search engine capable to recognize idioms. And by the way, I think that you should be spending more time trying to answer questions and less time trying to push people around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one looks very close to this meaning: [Give an arm and a leg for (something)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+an+arm+and+leg+for)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the metaphor "to pay a high price for something".

Alternatively, use the proverb ***There is no such thing as a free lunch***, which means it is impossible to get something for nothing, there is always a price to pay.

If you mean that you have to pay a very high price to get the things you want and you have doubts about it, or you are not sure if it's worth it, you can say ***The game is not worth the candle.*** This idiom is a bit old-fashioned though.